# How does a type-1 hypervisor virtualize a guest page table?

Tags: memory-management, virtualization, virtual-memory, hypervisor

I understand that CR3 contains the pointer to the page table. So I guess that VMenter changes CR3 to a virtualized register that's specific to the guest VM. Then the guest can load and swap page tables as usual, while the SLAT translates the guest physical pages to actual physical pages. Is that what happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using EPT, there is no need to virtualize the guest page tables at all. CR3 is simply loaded with the guest value.

Comment: So the guest uses the raw CR3 register, and the register is saved/restored when switching between the hypervisor and other guests?

Comment: I inferred when I wrote this answer that you are talking about Intel processors. Upon rereading your question, I'm not sure why I thought that. On Intel processors, CR3 is saved in the VMCS by VM exit and loaded from the VMCS by vmlaunch/vmresume.